# Rails: Controller dumps data in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a simple controller with `def index` having the following code:

```
@companies = Company.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

But in the view I get these errors appended after all the `companies` are being displayed:

`[#<Company id: 4, title: "Testing #1(1)", created_at: "2013-02-05 19:14:04", updated_at: "2013-02-05 19:14:04">, #<Company id: 7, title: "Testing #1 1", created_at: "2013-02-05 19:34:48", updated_at: "2013-02-05 19:34:48">]`

Updated with the view code:

```
= @companies.each do |company|
    %li
      .box
        .c
          %h2
            = link_to company.title, company
```

Comment: Please show your view code.

Comment: If the problem is with view then you should post the view code too. :)

Comment: @jdl: Correct, sorry about that - updated.

Comment: @SybariteManoj: Correct, sorry about that - updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= @companies.each do |company|`

The equals sign in Haml means "print the result of this expression." You're seeing the array of companies on the page because you asked for it.

Use a hyphen instead.

`- @companies.each do |company|`